# Implement photo disperse transition similar to Photos on iPad

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

On the iPad, when you tap an album in Photos, the photos in the album "explode" out from the stack of photos and align neatly into a grid. That's a very cool transition and I want to try to replicate it, but I could not find any open source projects that have attempted to do just that. How could this be accomplished?

The setup is two view controllers, currently segueing via the usual push transition. The first view controller already has the assets collections `PHFetchResult`, and it could easily obtain the assets for each collection. I understand one must use the `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate`, but how this specific transition effect can be accomplished is what I'm wondering about. Wondering if anyone has already attempted this (in Objective-C or Swift preferably Swift), and if not, how it can be implemented.

[image]

Comment: I believe that's a transition between two UICollectionViewLayouts. You should check out this year's and last year's WWDC videos; I'm pretty sure they have one covering this (and maybe some sample code).

Answer (score 0):

A search for “UICollectionView Photo Stack” will get you pointed in the right direction.

Example? http://skeuo.com/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial

Ultimately, you're going to be dealing with creating one layout that stacks all of the items in one spot. When the item is tapped, you invalidate the layout and introduce the grid-based layout.